# Symfony 3.x form with subforms creating by createFormBuilder() without FormBuilderInterface

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

Goog day!
I've read a lot of stackoverflow's articles and didn't find anything about this problem:

```
$checkForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('someField', ChoiceType::class, [//someOptions])
    ...(many add)
    ->getForm();
$filterForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('someField', ChoiceType::class, [//someOptions])
    ...(many add)
    ->getForm();
```

Now I want to embed these forms! **That's all!** But I didn't find anything about embeding with the ready forms, not that extends AbstractType.

I tried to write something like this:

```
$this->createFormBuilder([$checkForm, $filterForm]);
```

but in this way couldn't to render them in the simply way, and I understand that this way is wrong.

**ADDITION:**
The task is to choose fields, that will be in a sql query and choose the filters which filters the data. I need to render two forms individually, but submit button has one to both forms.

I'll be very thankfull, if somebody could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Than sounds weird. What do you mean by embed these forms? What's the goal you are trying to accomplish by that?

Comment: You didn't ready anything about it because the system does not support it.  Turn your two forms into form types and move on.

Comment: Can you maybe explain "why" you need to embed forms? Is it that you instead need two different forms on the same page, and then be able to respond differently to the different forms.

Comment: The main cause of using embedded forms is to have a possibility to submit by one button both forms.

Comment: Which is exactly what form types will allow you to do.  To put it politely, the Symfony forms component is one of the most highly engineered components out there.  Use it exactly the way it was intended to be used or be prepared to face a constant stream of problems.

Comment: I spend a lot of time for studying this question, and then you said me this I think you are right.
I was afraid a lot of classes(two for each table, I have 6 tables, which I need to render the same way) which I need to create for little task, but now I think it is a right way to do this.
But I still ask: can this problem decided in another way? Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: Maybe someone else has an idea.  I'm the wrong person to ask.  I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to adjust the form component to handle a few cases that are "outside of the box" and finally gave up.  I no longer use the form component.  It works great as long as it is used exactly as intended.